# getting 404 error when generating allure report in protractor using allure command line tool

Tags: typescript, maven, jasmine, protractor, allure

I am trying to generate allure report in protractor for the first time,

To generate allure report I am using jasmine allure reporter:1.0.2 and allure-commandline tool:2.7.0 versions

In my conf file I have added the code for generating xml results in a specific folder and then I am using allure-commandline tool to generate html report which gets generated in a folder named "Allure-report" in the project home directory, but now when I open the index.html file generated by using allure-commandline tool then I see 404 error in the different sections of report

Further I also tried to run following commands :-

**mvn site -Dallure.results_pattern= F:\Backup\Protractor-Workspace\Typescript_framework\Test_results\Allure-result** ,this command to generate html report from xml files which get generated upon running spec files.

and also tried to start jetty server using command :-

**mvn jetty:run -Djetty.port=1332** this command starts jetty server

but in both cases, I got error:-

**The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory**

Further, To explain further, I also tried to start jetty server from inside node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter folder but found that there is no pom.xml file in it due to which I again got "no POM in this directory" error

Please let me know what I should do now?

Below is the code I wrote in conf.ts file for generation of allure report :-

```
var AllureReporter = require('./node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      resultsDir: './Test_results/Allure-result'
        })
      );
  var allure = require('allure-commandline');
  var generation = allure(['generate', './Test_results/Allure-result']);
   generation.on('exit', function(exitCode:any) {
      console.log('Generation is finished with code:', exitCode);
    });
   },
```

Below are the screenshot of my project folder structure and the html report with 404 not found error

[report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8qsB.jpg)

[Project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKxJZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not open index.html file like a normal html.

allure will spin up a web server.

```
"scripts": {
"allure": "node_modules/.bin/allure generate ./allure-results -c && allure open"
},
```

add this to your script in package.json.

After your allure-results folder is created (i.e) test completes run `npm run allure`

[image]

[image]

After you run `npm run allure`. Your default browser will automatically open the report.

Comment: Thanks It worked like a charm I was able to generate the report and also results got published but one problem is still there that if any testcase fails then when I try to run command  allure given in package.json then it does not opens the report and also does not publishes the result in the reportso is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you delete your allure-results before starting your test?

Comment: please ignore the above comment , I want to thank you your solution worked like a charm but one requirement is that If I want to include screenshot for failed testcases then how to do it in allure

Comment: Yes I delete my results before running new tests

Comment: After your test completes please check if allure-results folder is created on failures also.If that folder is not created you will face issues in running the command

Comment: It is getting created There is no issue in creation of that folder and also when I run npm run allure command then it shows the failed results in report actually I was not able to view report in edge browser but when I change my default browser to chrome and then opened the report then every failed result was also logged in report

Comment: Can you please help me by telling me how to attach screenshot for failed testcases in allure report

Comment: afterEach(function(done){
      browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
        allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
          return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
        }, 'image/png')();
        done();
      })
    });

Comment: add the above in your afterEach hook . Just check the test status if its pass or fail before adding screenshots.

Comment: firstly, I am not able to find the code by which we can find pass or fail status of each test so please share its code and secondly,please give the screenshot of how this will be included in each spec file as right now when I include this code in each spec then it gives import error.