# Allure report is empty after generation

Tags: allure, newman

I'm using allure 2.8.1. I've installed it with NPM into my docker container. After it I run `allure generate test-results` command to generate allure report from junit xml's, that are generated with newman tool.

In report directory there appears an empty directory `data/attachments` and directory `data/test-cases` with all test cases from junit xml's.

Example of test-case xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="test-collection-2" tests="1" time="0.463">
  <testsuite name="Test succeed request" id="b3ce6542-d493-4206-b67b-e74e4ca58fde" tests="2" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.463">
    <testcase name="Status code is 200" time="0.463"/>
    <testcase name="Content-Type is present" time="0.463"/>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

After I open generated input html there appears nothing.
[image]

Can you please assist me with this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting 404 error when generating allure report in protractor using allure command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138595/getting-404-error-when-generating-allure-report-in-protractor-using-allure-comma)

Comment: have you tried using `allure serve test-results` command instead of `generate`? `serve` should generate and automatically open/serve report for you

Answer (score 5):

Allure needs a web server to open reports. After generating we cannot simply open the `index.html` file.
To open generated report in your local machine, there are two ways

1. Allure's default `open` command.

```
allure open path/to/report
```

This will open the report in your default web browser.

2. Run a simple HTTP server in the reports folder, and open it in a browser.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8626
```

now open `0.0.0.0:8626` in your browser.

If you are uploading the generated webserver directory, this will work without any problem.

Comment: In python3 instead of SimpleHTTPServer, use:

$ python3 -m http.server 8626